# Hamiltonian circuit in at least one component

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, computational-complexity, np-complete, hamiltonian-path

I'm having trouble proving that the problem stated in the title is NP-complete, specifically by reduction from Hamiltonian circuit.

Intuitively it's clear - Hamiltonian circuit in one graph is NP-complete, and this problem can be thought of as "Hamiltonian circuit in at least one of several graphs", so an algorithm could check each graph for a circuit and return "yes" if at least one contains the circuit.

But, from an admittedly meticulous point of view, a reduction should be shown from one graph $A$ to graph $B$, s.t. graph $A$ has a Hamiltonian circuit iff graph $B$ has a component with a Hamiltonian circuit.

I believe that such a reduction would be near-trivial... What am I missing?
Thanks :)

Comment: Do you mean connected component? Or just any subset of vertices and edges?

Comment: What have you tried so far in constructing $B$ from $A$?  You should write out one or two attempts and analyze what goes awry in them.  It really shouldn't take much effort to fix what's wrong, the important thing is getting started.

Comment: @Soke, I mean connected component.

Comment: @Erick, I tried returning the same graph, connecting components, breaking up to components.. If something had worked I wouldn't be asking you guys ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so this a brave attempt at answering my own question:

Upon a graph $G$ (an input for Hamiltonian circuit), the reduction will check if $G$ has more than one connected components, and if so, will output a graph with only two vertices and one edge, i.e. with no Hamiltonian circuits anywhere.
If $G$ has only one connected component, the reduction will output $G$.

The reduction takes polynomial time since finding the number of connected components takes polynomial time, and outputting the graphs clearly takes polynomial time.

Now, $G$ can contain a Hamiltonian circuit only if it has one connected component. So,
$G$ has a Hamiltonian circuit <=> $G$ has a Hamiltonian circuit and only one connected component <=> the reduction outputted $G$.

Comment: Great job!  Looks correct to me (certainly the overall strategy is exactly right).  The key observation was that $G$ cannot be Hamiltonian if it has more than one component, allowing you to eliminate those cases in polynomial time by returning a simple graph with no Hamilton circuits.

Comment: @ErickWong I'm skeptical -- doesn't the problem say the problem is finding a Hamiltonian circuit in at least one component? So even if there are multiple connected components, the problem is still difficult. I don't think poochon is eliminating those cases, rather adding an edge betwen the components? I'm not 100% sure but that's what it seems

Comment: @Soke No, the problem is not about *finding* a Hamiltonian circuit.  The formal decision problem is to determine membership in the language "all graphs which have a Hamiltonian circuit in at least one component".  The OP is specifically looking for a [Karp reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp_reduction) from HAMILTONIAN, and the construction looks good to me.  There is nothing in the solution about adding an edge between components, so I think you may be confused :).

Comment: @ErickWong Thanks, I'm a little rusty on algorithms. What does OP mean when they say "if so, will ouptut a graph with only two vertices and one edge, i.e. with no hamiltonian circuits anywhere"?

Comment: @Soke A reduction in this context is a function which takes as input a graph and returns another graph (of course it must satisfy other properties as well).  The quoted statement is declaring the output value of the function in the case that the input has $>1$ component.  The output is simply a path of length one: o-o.

Comment: @Soke, on an input $G$ with no Hamiltonian circuits, the reduction has to output a graph with no Hamiltonian circuits in any component. When we receive a graph with multiple components there is surely no Hamiltonian circuit, so output a graph with no circuits in any component - just a simple graph with one edge.